# Understanding for ember-cli/loader.js require._stats properties

Tags: javascript, performance, ember.js, ember-cli

I've tried searching a variety of google searches and whether it's the bloated word require or unfriendliness to ./_ I cannot find information around this.

I'm digging into `require._stats` to try and understand the performance of my application based on modules defined, used, etc and the properties under `require._stats` look like useful tools into discovering this information.

I have a rough idea of what a few of the following mean but am curious on solid definitions for the following fields that pop up after typing `require._stats` in the dev console (linking to any external resources is appreciated as well):

1. define
2. exports
3. findDeps
4. findModule
5. modules
6. pendingQueueLength
7. reify
8. require
9. resolve
10. resolveRelative

Comment: You've tagged this with [tag:requirejs] but there's no `_stats` symbol anywhere in the source code of RequireJS. What specific tool are you talking about exactly?

Comment: Thanks @Louis, looks like the application I'm looking at is getting these stats from ember-cli's [loader.js](https://github.com/ember-cli/loader.js) and is not part of require.js. I will update the tags and title to reflect these details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ember.js application that I'm analyzing is getting these stats from ember-cli's loader.js and is not part of require.js. Looking at the code in [loader.js](https://github.com/ember-cli/loader.js/blob/master/lib/loader/loader.js), we can see that each field provides the following information by tracking `heimdall.increment` statements and looking a [a few definitions provided early in the source](https://github.com/ember-cli/loader.js/blob/master/lib/loader/loader.js#L102):

1. define - The number of modules defined. With this loader, there will be extra modules defined as [a few dummy modules are loaded in the source](https://github.com/ember-cli/loader.js/blob/master/lib/loader/loader.js#L342). It's possible for modules defined with the same name to not be counted.
2. exports - The number of modules exported
3. findDeps - The number of times dependencies are searched for. This should correspond
4. findModule - The number of times a module is looked for. This could be whenever a module is required, or when it is unregistered with `unsee`
5. modules - The number of modules registered
6. pendingQueueLength - The amount of times a module is found and added to the the pending queue for processing that is not already pending and not executed
7. reify - The number of times a modules set of exports is run
8. require - The number of require statements of modules
9. resolve - The number of times modules are resolved
10. resolveRelative - The number of times modules are resolved at a relative path (those starting with `.`)

It is important to note that it's entirely possible to wrap a dependency in a module (sometimes unintentionally with the "magic" of build automation tools!) so you may not have a complete picture of the performance of your dependency management, as you might have an instance of some kind of loader within a module being loaded via the loader.js providing the `requirejs._stats` that you are looking at.